# Storing hierarchical data into hdf5 - how to structure them

Tags: python, hdf5

I need to store hierarchical data structure into hdf5, where majority of the leaf nodes are non-array types (strings or scalars), onyl a few of them are homogeneous arrays. Those data look similar to this:

```
/simulation-20130312_13:33p1435
   +- input
   |  +- gravity = 9.81
   |  +- timeScale = 1.0
   |  +- userTitle = 'real'
   |  +- flowRates = [ 1.1, 2.1 ]
   |  +- material
   |     +- density = 1234.2
   |     +- young = 1.123e6
   |     +- temp = 290.2
   +- finished = '20130312_16:21'
   +- host = 'efflux.local'
   +- series
      +- t = [0,1e-5,2e-5,...,3.4e-4]
      +- Ek = [0,...]
/simulation-20130312_13:55p1657
   ...
   ...
```

Data under each simulation are structured similarly, but not necessarily identically, so I think using a table is not possible.

Should I create groups for all leaves, and always set the value as array attached to that leaf- and use 1x1 array if the value is scalar? Should I use group attributes for all data except real arrays? Is that not going to be confusing for people working with those files?

I have virtually no experience with hdf5; the number of data will be relatively small, there is not much concern about efficienty at this moment - the important thing is to be able to import data easily into Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 stands for **Hierarchical Data Format**, it is clearly the right tool to store a hierarchy like yours.

I would recommend that you store your leaves as datasets:

- use scalar datasets for scalars (strings, numbers, `flowRates` can also be considered a scalar of type *array of size 2*)
- use simple datasets for the time series

and create groups for all the other nodes, like this:

```
/simulation-20130312_13:33p1435       # root group: /
   +- input                           # group: /input
   |  +- gravity = 9.81               # scalar double
   |  +- timeScale = 1.0              # scalar double
   |  +- userTitle = 'real'           # scalar string
   |  +- flowRates = [ 1.1, 2.1 ]     # scalar array[2]
   |  +- material                     # group: /input/material
   |     +- density = 1234.2          # scalar double
   |     +- young = 1.123e6           # scalar double
   |     +- temp = 290.2              # scalar double
   +- finished = '20130312_16:21'     # scalar string
   +- host = 'efflux.local'           # scalar string
   +- series                          # group: /series
      +- t = [0,1e-5,2e-5,...,3.4e-4] # simple dataset double
      +- Ek = [0,...]                 # simple dataset double
```

The import in Matlab should be a piece of cake.